# use character data type to keep primary key values sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqldatatypes

I have a number of doubts about data type. 
I have in a table customers and suppliers , which is better? create two columns one to take only the C or S if they are customers or suppliers and another colum ​​that is an identifier. And two columns form the primary key. Or just a column where records start by C or S and then the code identifiacion, eg C3663 or S2707.

In another table I have a column as a primary key that takes numerical values ​​of 5 digits, eg 12345, What kind of data would be the appropriate? char (5), numeric (5,0) or int 
I thought char (5) why ID makes no numerical operation

Comment: Sooner or later a customer will also be supplier (or the other way around). Use a separate key/identifier column and have SupplierNumber and CustomerNumber as separate columns.

Answer (score 1):

For the first example, if you just want to identify whether the record is for customer or supplier then

You can either have a column say `EntityType` with datatype `char(1)` having values either `C` or `S.`

Or, you can have two `bit` type column say `IsCustomer` and `IsSupplier` which will hold values `True/False` based on the entity type being customer or supplier.

For Second example, `eg 12345`; if you think you will have to perform some numeric calculation on that column value then it make sense to have it defined as `Int` or `Numeric` type but in case there is no numerical operation going to be performed on this column value and it defines some kind of code then declare it as `CHAR(5)`. Again, if you sure that the size is fixed to be 5 characters length then only declare it as `CHAR(5)` else consider declaring it as of `VARCHAR` type.

Answer (score 1):

For your first table of Customers or Suppliers: do not combine the numeric code with the character designation. Use two separate fields. If you combine them then all your queries that isolate Customers from Suppliers will require a bit of extra logic (and they will be somewhat less efficient).

For your second question, I would use int. It will be smaller than numeric(5,0). And you don't want to use char(5) for this because it's less restrictive - it will permit bogus values like 'abcde'.